# jQuery select list removes all options

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, firebug

I have a `<select>` list, which has been populated with several options, but want to remove those options to start again.

I am using jQuery and have tried the following:

```
$("#selectId").length = 0;
```

But this seems to have no effect.

Part of my problem is that I am using Firebug to debug the JavaScript, but the debugger does not break at the breakpoint, so I cannot see what is going on. Should it break when the JavaScript is within the `<head>` of my HTML file?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

this would do:

```
$('#selectId').html('');
```

Comment: doesnt this removes the <select> entirely? I would like to bring the select to the original state without any options

Comment: @therealprashant: `.html` sets the *inner* html of an element, so setting it to an empty string will remove any child nodes, but spare the dropdown list itself.

Answer (score 30):

This works too.

```
$("#selectId option").remove();
```

Comment: This seems like the neater solution

Comment: I like this better than the accepted answer because it is safer by removing the specific "option" tags.

Answer (score 11):

`$("#selectId").empty();` works for me.

The `$("#selectId option").remove();` removed the select from the DOM.

Currently using jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.1

Answer (score 7):

The fastest way to accomplish this:

```
$("#selectId").empty();
```

Here are some tests:
http://jsperf.com/find-remove-vs-empty

I take no credit for these tests.
See this stack overflow question: [How do you remove all the options of a select box and then add one option and select it with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824/how-do-you-remove-all-the-options-of-a-select-box-and-then-add-one-option-and-se#answer-1917744)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#selectId").options.length = 0;
```

That won't actually work as written because it's using a jQuery selector. It'd work if you used a straight DOM getElementById on the select list, though. Either AKX's or d.'s responses will set you right.

Answer (score 1):

If without jquery:

[javascript SELECT remove()](http://javascript.gakaa.com/select-remove-4-0-5-.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try This for Multiple Select Drop Down.

$('#FeatureId').multiselect("deselectAll", false).multiselect("refresh");