# Clearing select options with javascript on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onchange, html-select

Before you -1 this for being such a simple question read further, because ive spent a while searching and cant figure it out. What i have is 5 select boxes. Each ones results depend on what is selected before it. There is no submit button. I just need the  to change based on whats selected in the previous box and so far i have that. Oh and the results are being pulled from a database. The problem is when you select an option in lets say box 1, box 2 options appear, but when you go and select an option in box 1 again, they options are just stacked on the others. I need them to clear when its changed again. I'll post the js i have and if you need anything else just ask.

p.s. im getting the options using php-mysql. 
p.s.s this site has to be finished by tomorrow so im kinda in a rush. Please dont waste time telling me this is a stupid question or what not.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
$(function () { //When the page is finished loading run this code
    $('#country').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<!--Base url taken out-->/discovery/aLoad",
            success: function (data) {
                eval(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('failed');
            },
            data: {
                country: getSelectValues('#country')
            },
            type: 'POST'
        });
    });
 });

     function changeSearchBar (newBar) {
    //remove the crap
    function ClearOptions(country)
    {
    document.getElementById('country').options.length = 0;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= newBar.length; i++) {
        newBar[i].id = newBar[i][0];
        newBar[i].name = newBar[i][1];
        $('#group').append(
            $('<option></option>').attr('value', newBar[i].id).text(newBar[i].name)
        );
    }
     }

     function getSelectValues (sId) {
    var str = "";

    $(sId +" option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).val() + ",";
    });

    return str.replace(/.$/g, '');
}
```

Comment: Your ClearOptions function looks good, but I don't see where you call it.  It is defined wihtin changeSearchBar, but never called.  I think if you call it right before your for loop you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your long post you just need to remove all `select` child's before starting to append the new option from the AJAX request.

Try something like this before your `for` loop:

```
$('#group').html('');​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/57TYu/2/

Comment: It's like your a genius or something! :D Yeah i know it was a long post. Didnt know how to clarify it. But yes that worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Wait, sorry, that got rid of the option to select multiple

Comment: I need to be able to select multiple and have all the 2nd box options associated with those two return. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get it, when you say "select multiple" its something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/57TYu/

Comment: by select multiple i mean <select id="country" multiple>. The code you gave me only gives the options in the next box for one of the values selected in the first box.

Comment: Hey dude it works what you said. The guy im working for just has a messed up stored procedure. So thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I think this is basically what you are trying to do:

[How do you remove all the options of a select box and then add one option and select it with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824/using-core-jquery-how-do-you-remove-all-the-options-of-a-select-box-then-add-o)

Basically, find the 'option' tags inside the select and remove them.

```
$('select').find('option').remove()
```

will clear all the select boxes.

This will append the data, which is assume are the options in their place:

```
$('select').find('option').remove().end().append(data);
```

I think that is what you are looking for.