# Dynamically set select-options with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I dynamically set the options from my html select field with Javascript?
This is my page setup:

```
<form name="test">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='dataleft'>Product: </td>
      <td><select name='inptProduct'></select></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I have all values in an array. This is the location to set the `<option>`s.

```
for(var i = 0; i < productArray.length; i++) {
    console.log("<option value='" + productArray[i] + "'>" + productArray[i] + "</option>");
}
```

PS: jQuery can be used.

---

**Solution:**
This is the final solution I was looking for. It does not apply the new options to the select field. It removes all first, and then adds the new ones:

```
var optionsAsString = "";
for(var i = 0; i < productArray.length; i++) {
    optionsAsString += "<option value='" + productArray[i] + "'>" + productArray[i] + "</option>";
}
$("select[name='inptProduct']").find('option').remove().end().append($(optionsAsString));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824/how-do-you-remove-all-the-options-of-a-select-box-and-then-add-one-option-and-se

Answer (score 48, accepted):

wellyou have almost done it all:

```
var optionsAsString = "";
for(var i = 0; i < productArray.length; i++) {
    optionsAsString += "<option value='" + productArray[i] + "'>" + productArray[i] + "</option>";
}
$( 'select[name="inptProduct"]' ).append( optionsAsString );
```

**EDIT** removed $ wrapper around last `optionsAsString` as `append` automatically converts strings

Comment: @vemv *again* - maybe its time to create a function that do this

Comment: best answer, simple & easy.

Answer (score 27):

```
var $inputProduct = $("select[name='inputProduct']")

$(productArray).each(function(i, v){ 
    $inputProduct.append($("<option>", { value: v, html: v }));
});
```

Comment: this will work - but adding the options in one go is more efficient. Not that it matters if it's just one pulldown in a page.

Comment: what makes you think this doesn't do that?

Comment: you are running .append for every member of the productArray

Comment: Thanks for this hunter. Is there a function to replace all options, instead of appending them?

Comment: write `$inputProduct.html("")` before looping through to clear current options

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that the array `productArray` is a simple array, with each element being the value of the option, and the desired title for that option.

```
$( 'select[name="inptProduct"]' )
  .html( '<option>' + productArray.join( '</option><option>' ) + '</option>' );
```

Example:

```
productArray = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

// With the original code being

<select name="inptProduct">
  <option>There could be no options here</option>
  <option>Otherwise, any options here will be overwritten</option>
</select>

// Running the code above would output

<select name="inptProduct">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function onLoad() {

  var type = new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");

    var $select = $("select[name='XXXXXType']")
    alert($select);
    $(type).each(function(i, v){
        $select.append($("<option>", { value: v, html: v }));
      });

}
```

```
<select name="XXXXXType" id="XXXXXType"></select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for people who don't want to use jQuery:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('select')

const arr = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange']

arr.forEach(value => {
  const option = document.createElement('option')
  option.innerHTML = value
  select.appendChild(option)
})
```

```html
<select id="select"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you not insisting for pure JavaScript to do the job, you can easily done the job using jQuery.

```
<form name="test">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='dataleft'>Product: </td>
      <td><select id='inptProduct'></select></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>


for (var i = 0; i < productArray.length; i++) {
    $("#inptProduct").append('<option value=' + if_you_want_set_value + '>' + productArray[i] + '</option>');
    }
```

Note that here I used the id of select tag. That's why I add the html part too. Hope you know how to add jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this:

`document.getElementById("selectid").innerHTML="<option value='foo'>FOO</option>"`;

Answer (score -5):

you can set id for the select id=inptProduct
Then do $('#inptProduct').val(yourselectValue)

Comment: First of all you don't need to set the id to access a node, secondly val does something completely different.

Comment: .val() will set the selected value of the select element.