# Changing a DropDownList items Depending on a value from another DropDownList( OnChange Event) ASP.NET Webpages

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Sorry for the dumb question, i used to use MVC and I've never done something like this before.

Alright so lets say I'm implementing a **Tickets system** where the user can book a ticket in a specific time and bus.

in the "Booking" page i have **2 DropDownLists**, one of them is for the time of the trip, and the other one for the seat position in that trip.

i want it so the Seat Position DropDownList **changes automatically** to show only the available seats when the user chooses the time from the first DropDownList. of course, there will be database with the available seats in each Trip.

***what i've realized** so far: i have to make an OnChange event handler with javascript, but what i cant realize is how im supposed to bring the list of seats from the database to the javascript.

note: im using asp.net wepages with c# and razor syntax

thanks in advance and sorry for the long paragraphs :)

Comment: Pure javascript or you can use jquery?

Comment: i can use it but im not too good in it.

Comment: Could someone please answer this with codebehind using C#? I am after the same solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var ddl_2_items = [ "one", "two", "three" ];

$("ddl_1").change(function(e){

var filteredValues = ddl_2_items.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.indexOf($(this).val()) != -1;
});

var ddl2 = $("ddl_2");
ddl2.empty();
filteredValues .each(function(obj){
        ddl2.append($("<option>", { value: v, html: v }));
      });


});
```

thats the basics

see more [Dynamically set select-options with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247423/dynamically-set-select-options-with-javascript)