# How can I remove an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an array like this:

```
var array = [
              {SchoolId: 2  ,GraderId: 465 , SchoolGraderName: "Example1256"},
              {SchoolId: 2  ,GraderId: 654,SchoolGraderName: "Example45"},
              {SchoolId: 2  ,GraderId: 876,SchoolGraderName: "Example895"},
              {SchoolId: 34 ,GraderId: 796,SchoolGraderName:"Example2156"},
              {SchoolId: 45 ,GraderId: 356,SchoolGraderName:"Example315"},
              {SchoolId: 45 ,GraderId: 457,SchoolGraderName:"Example56715"}
              {SchoolId: 45 ,GraderId: 678,SchoolGraderName:"Example37675"}
              {SchoolId: 45 ,GraderId: 465 ,SchoolGraderName:"Example97685615"}
            ]
```

I am trying to delete the whole objects Where the GraderId is some value (:

```
$(function() {
            $("#schoolGraders").on("dblclick",
                function() {
                    $.each(array,function(i,r){
                        if (r.GraderId == $(this).val()) {
                            r.removeItem;
                       }
                });
        });
```

the code above does not work.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="schoolGraders" style="width: 80%; height: 200px" 
multiple></select>
```

I generate the options like this:

```
item = "";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "address" + $(this).val(),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function (res) {
                    var iteem = "";
                    $.each(res,
                        function (i, r) {
                            iteem += '<option value="' + r.id + 
                             '">' + r.title + '</option>';
                        });
                    $("#graderSchools").html(iteem);
                });
```

Is there any condition in JavaScript So I can remove objects WHERE the GraderId is some value ?

Comment: Why are we using jQuery?  less is more.  jQuery made sense five years ago.  Not so much now.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Rather than using an array, consider using a Set.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Comment: @PeterB no, it removes only one element, I want to remove an object with a Condition which is fiven GraderId.

Comment: how do you render the options?

Comment: @IamL just added into question

Comment: @M.imp The accepted answer with 14000+ upvotes says "Find the index of the array element you want to remove [....] then remove that index with splice". This totally applies, esp. when combined with the other answers that show how to find the index without using indexOf.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps, lets say you want to remove object where *GraderId* is *876*.

```js
var array = [
              {SchoolId: 2  ,GraderId: 465 , SchoolGraderName: "Example1256"},
              {SchoolId: 2  ,GraderId: 654,SchoolGraderName: "Example45"},
              {SchoolId: 2  ,GraderId: 876,SchoolGraderName: "Example895"},
              {SchoolId: 34 ,GraderId: 796,SchoolGraderName:"Example2156"},
              {SchoolId: 45 ,GraderId: 356,SchoolGraderName:"Example315"},
              {SchoolId: 45 ,GraderId: 457,SchoolGraderName:"Example56715"},
              {SchoolId: 45 ,GraderId: 678,SchoolGraderName:"Example37675"},
              {SchoolId: 45 ,GraderId: 465 ,SchoolGraderName:"Example97685615"}
            ]
            
array.forEach((item, index) => {
    if(item.GraderId === 876){
    delete array[index]
  }
})

console.log(array)
```

Comment: didn't work: 
$(function() {
                $("#schoolGraders").on("dblclick",
                    function () {
                        var deletedGraderId = $(this).val();
                        $("#schoolGraders option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").remove();

                        array.forEach((item, index) => {
                            alert("hi");
                            if (item.GraderId === deletedGraderId) {
                                delete array[index];
                            }
                        });

                    });
            });

Comment: Doesnt the delete in JS only set the element to undefined?

Comment: @DragonInTraining No. [Delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) removes a property from an object. Run this in console `let name = {family: "Tosh", first: "Peter"}; delete name.first; name;`

Comment: DragonInTraining is right, this does ***exactly*** the same as `array[index] = undefined;` and also `array.length` does not change.

Comment: Oh yes, in case of arrays, you are right. Delete does not remove the item, it sets it to undefined. To remove the item, use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var array = [
  {SchoolId: 2  ,GraderId: 465 , SchoolGraderName: "Example1256"},
  {SchoolId: 2  ,GraderId: 654,SchoolGraderName: "Example45"},
  {SchoolId: 2  ,GraderId: 876,SchoolGraderName: "Example895"},
  {SchoolId: 34 ,GraderId: 796,SchoolGraderName:"Example2156"},
  {SchoolId: 45 ,GraderId: 356,SchoolGraderName:"Example315"},
  {SchoolId: 45 ,GraderId: 457,SchoolGraderName:"Example56715"}
  {SchoolId: 45 ,GraderId: 678,SchoolGraderName:"Example37675"}
  {SchoolId: 45 ,GraderId: 465 ,SchoolGraderName:"Example97685615"}
]

const filteredArr = array.filter(item => item.GraderId !== $(this).val())
```

Then maps items to HTML using this filteredArray

Comment: does this delete the object where the GraderId is $(this).val() ?

Comment: @M.imp yes and will return a new array without those values. Then use the new array to add items to HTML.

Comment: Didn't work for me:
$("#schoolGraders").on("dblclick",
                    function () {
                        var deletedGraderId = $(this).val();
                        $("#schoolGraders option[value=" + deletedGraderId + "]").remove();

                        array = array.filter(item => item.GraderId !== deletedGraderId);

                    }); @Dharmaraj

Comment: @M.imp can you provide some HTML around that select?

Comment: There is nothing more except the html code I have given in question

Comment: @M.imp are you trying to add add options to select? Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247423/dynamically-set-select-options-with-javascript). That way set the filteredArray to select.

Comment: No, I'm trying to delete an object with the condition of equal given GraderId

Comment: @M.imp that's not clear what you are trying to delete. I only see a select. What is that 'object' in this case?

Comment: Objects are gotten from server (Ajax) and are considered as options

Answer (score 1):

I found the way, Thank you all.
Here I wanted to share it to all so everbody can use it.

```
$("#schoolGraders").on("dblclick",
                function () {

                    var deletedGraderId = $(this).val();

                    var schoolId = $("#selectedSchools").val();

                    $.each(array,
                        function (i, r) {
                            if (r.GraderId == deletedGraderId && r.SchoolId == schoolId) {
                                array.splice(i, 1);
                            }
                        });


                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method filters an array removing elements that do not pass the condition argument.
It's usally the best way to remove array element in js.

I think the main problem in your code is `this.val()`. `this` is quite an advanced js concept, as it has multiple meanings depending on the context. In your case, I think it refers to the current value `r` of your `each` callback, and not the `select` element. I prefer `evt.currentTarget` instead.

The following code must be called inside the `done` callback as the  won't exist before. This kind of error, due to inexistent elements, is silently ignored by jQuery.

```js
var schoolGraders = document.getElementBydId('schoolGraders');
schoolGraders.addEventListener('dblclick', (evt)=> {
    array.filter((obj,i)=>  obj.GraderId != +evt.currentTarget.value)
});
```

However I'd be vary of using the double click event as it has [poor support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event#browser_compatibility) on Android browsers.