# jQuery select add update and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

xample: considering that i have 2 hotel rooms that can be sold with 2 options BB or HB, when I change the option of select 1 (taking 1 room in BB) or I change the option of select 2 (taking 1 room in HB, selecting again option 1 or option 2 the number of rooms still available must result as only 1

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rates1').change(function() {
    var val = parseInt($(this).val());
    var optionlength = ($('#rates1 option').length);
    var optionremove = optionlength - val - 1;
    //alert(optionremove);
    $('#rates2 option').remove();
  });
});
</script>


<select id="rates1" class="selectclass">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>

</select><br />
<select id="rates2" class="selectclass">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You cannot have two elements with the same `id`

Comment: I don't understand your requirement.  Please elaborate and provide the jQuery code that you've tried to write to solve this problem.

Comment: I updated your question with the code from your comment.

Comment: try using google translate to clarify your question

Comment: If you want a dynamic data in dependent combos use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824/how-do-you-remove-all-the-options-of-a-select-box-and-then-add-one-option-and-se

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to show the options in `select2` based on `select1`.

If that is your point then, try this

```
<select id="rates1" class="selectclass">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="50">1</option>
    <option value="100">2</option>
</select>
<select id="rates2" class="selectclass">
    <option data-rates1="1" value="0">0</option>
    <option data-rates1="1"  value="80">1</option>
    <option data-rates1="2" value="160">2</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#rates1').on('change', function () {
    if ((this.value === '0') || (this.value === '50')) {
        $('#rates2 option[data-rates1=1]').show();
        $('#rates2 option[data-rates1=2]').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#rates2 option[data-rates1=1]').hide();
        $('#rates2 option[data-rates1=2]').show();

    }
});
```

Check out this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ueHMP/3/)

You may get confused of `data-rates`, it is nothing but [**custom data attributes**](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) in `HTML5`.

Hope you get my point.

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear, so I'm going to interpret it as: when an option in the first `<select>` tag is chosen, change the options available to select in the second `<select>` tag.

NOTE: you can't use the same id attribute for more than one item; the purpose of id's is to uniquely define a single item. In this case, I'll refer to the first `<select>` tag as `id="selectid1"` and the second `<select>` tag as `id="selectid2"`.

Try this code to remove the option "1" from the second select tag when the option "1" is selected in the first select tag: ([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xjHCz/3/))

```
$("#selectid1").change(function () {
    var selected_value = $("#selectid1 option:selected").val();

    // adds the default options each time the .change() handler is fired
    $("#selectid2").html("<option value=\"0\">0</option><option value=\"80\">1</option><option value=\"160\">2</option>");

    if (selected_value == 50) {
        $("#selectid2 option[value='80']").remove();
    }
});
```

The main takeaway is the .change() handler to detect when the selection has changed, and the syntax for selecting an option by value, which I found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery?rq=1).