# remove all options from select jquery but only one

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeall

I have a select that contain this values:

```
<select id="lstCities" class="valid" name="City">
<option value="OSNY">OSNY</option>
<option value="dd">dd</option>
<option value="OSffNY">OSffNY</option>
<option value="ANTONY">ANTONY</option>
<option value="0">Autre...</option>
</select>
```

How can I delete all options but i would like to keep only

```
 <option value="0">Autre...</option>
```

My problem is my list is dynamic sometimes I have 3,5,7,.... select + the last one `<option value="0">Autre...</option>`

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this question. I wasted 2 days trying to deal with multiple dynamic select boxes that for some stupid reason when they designed selects they didn't add a read-only option.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

select all options, then exclude the one with that value :

```
$('#lstCities option[value!="0"]').remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9dgV5/2/)

Comment: Thanks for that. My need of this code deals more with excluding a file from a concatenation and minification process headed by stream.pipe, but it still showed me what I needed to exclude it: `$('script[src!="variables.json"]').remove();` Thanks a bunch! -C§

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
$('#lstCities option:lt(-1)').remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T3Wsb/)

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#lstCities option[value!=0]').remove()
```

You should remove by value and not rely on the position of the option element to keep.

Answer (score 2):

If the option is always the last one, I hope this JavaScript code can help you:

```
var lastNode = $("#lstCities option").last();
var option = { value:lastNode.val(), text:lastNode.text() };

$('#lstCities').find('option').remove().end().append($('<option>',{
        value:option.value,
        text:option.text,
}));
```

Learned from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824/how-do-you-remove-all-the-options-of-a-select-box-and-then-add-one-option-and-se)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$("#selectList option").remove();
```

Comment: I apologize for posting code that doesn't pertain to this post. My code is for removing all items in a select list. If you want to keep one, refer to the above suggestions. Make note that options are just like arrays or the index of a string - the value begins at 0.