# Swap options between select Harvest Chosen select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am trying to swap all the options between two Harvest Chosen select boxes.  The scenario is I want to record details of a phone call.  The call can either be inbound or outbound.  If the call is outbound the I populate a select box (caller) with a list of possible values of those users that can make outbound calls and a second box (callee) with a list of possible values of those users they can make calls to.  If the user updates the call type to be inbound then I want to swap the select boxes around so that the callee's are in the caller box and vice versa.

I very nearly have this working except each time I change the call type it keeps appending the values onto the end of the select options in each respective caller/callee select rather than completely clearing them and replacing all values.

Would appreciate some help as to why this is happening.

See http://jsfiddle.net/RyHFK

HTML

```
<label for="call_type">Call Type:</label>
<select name="call_type" id="call_type" class="chosen">
    <option value="OUTGOING">Outgoing</option>
    <option value="INCOMING">Incoming</option>                                                  
</select>

<label for="caller">Caller:</label>
<select name="caller" id="caller" class="caller chosen">
   <option value="Caller 1">Caller 1</option>   
   <option value="Caller 2">Caller 2</option>   
   <option value="Caller 3">Caller 3</option>   
  <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
</select>

<label for="caller">Callee:</label>
<select name="callee" id="callee" class="callee chosen">
   <option value="Callee 1">Callee 1</option>   
   <option value="Callee 2">Callee 2</option>   
   <option value="Callee 3">Callee 3</option>   
   <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Take a look at this post and see if it works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824/how-do-you-remove-all-the-options-of-a-select-box-and-then-add-one-option-and-se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it's written, you are appending to the same arrays every time there is a change. Move your `calleeOptions` and `callerOptions` variables inside your change handler:

```
// on call type change
$('#call_type').change(function(){

    var callerOptions = [];
    var calleeOptions = [];
```

[Here's a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6v75c/)

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks, worked perfectly.