# internet explorer dropdown doesn't show value

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a strange problem. Everything works fine in Chrome/Firefox, but IE is bugging me. I have a simple triple dropdown to show a date. If the user already has filled in a date in the database this one will be shown whenever they load the page.

```
nDate = new Date(date);
d = nDate.getDate();
m = nDate.getMonth();
m++;
y = nDate.getFullYear();
$("#DAY").val(d);
$("#MONTH").val(m);
$("#YEAR").val(y);
```

My variable `date` is defined, 100% sure it gets filled in since it works fine in other browsers.

The format is: `'YYYY-MM-DD'`

Now the strange part is, if I print the values of the dropdown, they are shown correctly. So basically the dropdown has the right value selected, it just doesn't get shown. Anybody has an idea why?

Thx in advance.

Comment: remove the hashtag, and remove it from your id/class. IE doesn't like hashtags leading for naming convention on DOM objects.

Comment: +1 for IE doesn't like hashtags for names.

Comment: Hashtag in the name? Where do you see that? The field ID will be `DAY`, and the `$('#DAY')` is the jQuery way to select that from the DOM...

Comment: UweB is right.. thats part of the selector (selecting an ID)

Comment: hashtag is just to select the ID as stated by UweB

Comment: Can you provide a jsBin/Fiddle with what you are trying to do? Also, in which version of IE do you see the problem?

Comment: Which version of IE? Are you using jQuery2? This matters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the selected index property of the select.

e.g.

```
var d = nDate.getDate();
var daySel = $("#DAY")[0];
for(var i = 0; i < daySel.options.length; ++i) {
    if(daySel.options[i].value == d) {
       daySel.selectedIndex = i;
       break;
    }
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fApu/

Comment: Probably related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824/how-do-you-remove-all-the-options-of-a-select-box-and-then-add-one-option-and-se/2040837#2040837