# jQuery - Nullify dropdown values when there is a change in selection populated list

Tags: php, jquery

I am following this tutorial - http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/

The tutorial shows a populated two selects. I modified it to show three selects. Each depends on the other.

Scenario 1: As I chose a selection from 'Selection 1', the 'Selection 2' list is populated with 'Selection 3'. Till now it works correctly.

Scenario 2: When I change my selection in 'Selection 1', the 'Selection 2' list is reset and is built according 'Selection 1' - this is suppose as it should be. On the other hand without choosing anything from 'Selection 2', 'Selection 3' remains populated with the result from scenario 1 above. I want 'Selection 3' to lose its value whenever I change 'Selection 1'.

This is my jquery code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

    function getCity(val) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_city.php",
            data:'secondary_cat='+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#tertiary_cat").html(data);
            }
        });
    }


    function getState(val) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_state.php",
            data:'primary_cat='+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function selectCountry(val) {
        $("#search-box").val(val);
        $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change Selection 1 populate Selection 2 and empty Selection 3 using a code like this ones https://stackoverflow.com/a/47829/5209288