# onchange I would like to filter a drop down list that has a dynamic name

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with a complex javascript issue, please help.

There are 2 drop down lists, the name of the attributes are "dynamic". Users can add additional div's that logic is working fine so its not relevant to the issue I have now.

When the user selects a Product from the drop down list I want to display the year relevant to the Product Index. I am able to get the Product name and the suffix, but don;t know how to get or set the Fiscal Year attribute properties.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadYear(obj) {
        alert("The attribute name is " + obj.name);
        var suffix = obj.name.match(/\d+/);
        alert("the suffix is  " +suffix);

        alert(" how to get the name and value of Fiscal_Year attribute that changes dynamically");

    }
</script>

<div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <select name="[0].Product" onchange="loadYear(this);">
                                            <option value="15>Corporate HQ</option>
                                            <option value="16">Data Campaign</option>
                                            <option value="17">Digital Products </option>
                                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select name="[0].FISCAL_YEAR">
                                    <option value="15">FY15</option>
                                    <option value="16">FY16</option>
                                    <option value="17">FY17</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <select name="[1].Product" onchange="loadYear(this);">
                                            <option value="15>Corporate HQ</option>
                                            <option value="16">Data Campaign</option>
                                            <option value="17">Digital Products </option>
                                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select name="[1].FISCAL_YEAR">
                                    <option value="15">FY15</option>
                                    <option value="16">FY16</option>
                                    <option value="17">FY17</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery at all? (I can come up with a quick solution using jQuery, otherwise I'd have to do some research)

Comment: I am using Jquery for other logic. I am fine using it for this one too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the name like `[0].Product` cant you dynamically create name like `Product_0` and `FISCAL_YEAR_0`, that will be easy, because then in your loadYear function you can just do

```
obj.name.replace('Product_', '');
```

And that will give you the index of selected product.. then you can just use the javascript to access the year

Is it possible in your logic ?

Comment: I am using C# to retrive the values and adding the suffix this way is the only solution I know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
function loadYear(obj) {
    alert("The attribute name is " + obj.name);
    var suffix = obj.name.match(/\d+/);
    alert("the suffix is  " +suffix);

    // Get the year value from the year selection
    var selectedYear = obj.value;
    // Find the corresponding FISCAL_SELECT element
    var fiscalSelects = document.getElementsByName("[" + suffix + "].FISCAL_YEAR");
    if (fiscalSelects != null && fiscalSelects.length > 0) {
        // Set the value (assuming only one element exists)
        fiscalSelects[0].value = selectedYear;
    }
}
```

As requested, here is the last bit of that function implemented with jQuery:

```
// Get the year value from the year selection
var selectedYear = $(obj).val();
// Find the corresponding FISCAL_SELECT element
var fiscalSelects = $('[name="[' + suffix + '].FISCAL_YEAR"]');
if (fiscalSelects != null && fiscalSelects.length > 0) {
    // Set the value (assuming only one element exists)
    fiscalSelects[0].val(selectedYear);
}
```

Comment: I am trying this option now.

Comment: Hi I accept this as the answer to my question!!  If you don;t mind can you please provide me a solution using Jquery as well, I might have to move this part of the script to Jquery moving forward. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Updated answer to include jquery solution

Comment: Hi Pacifier, thanks for you help so far. I would like to ask one more question related to the same issue please. I am struggling with it. I would like to empty the drop down list and add new list from the database. I tried fiscalSelects.empty() and fiscalSelectsappend($('<option />', { value: item.fy_id, text: item.fy_year}));

Comment: I think it depends on where you put your logic. Those lines should do what you're trying to do as long as you have a good reference to the "fiscalSelects" object. Make sure that the instance of "fiscalSelects" you are using is an active reference to the DOM element. You might have to do another jquery select to get the proper reference. If all looks good there, you might want to look at the info here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47824/3586783